# Regenerate and Pull in new CSRF Token Through AJAX and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, csrf

I have a Backbone app over a Rails backend. I'm not having problems with sending the CSRF token, but I am having a problem where I logout and want to log back in, but it's not verifying the login because the CSRF token gets changed after a logout.

Is there a way to pull in this CSRF token without doing a full page request or should I just always make the browser do a full page refresh from the server after a logout to stop this from happening?

I'm okay with doing a full browser refresh if there's no other way around this CSRF problem, I just think my users get kind of a crappy experience because of CSRF, but I think they'll forgive me if their account is better protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the tutorial "Finally correctly dealing with Rails' CSRF protection and Backbone's AJAX" here: http://blog.softr.li/post/43146401263/finally-correctly-dealing-with-rails-csrf-protection

Comment: Sorry, but can you please send me the direct link next time? I actually had to google search it to find it and luckily found it within Google's cached version of what you sent. This helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay much attention to it cuz it's an ajax modal view with no url change. I've updated the URL now.

Comment: thank you, btw You're the man! I just gave up on this before, but it's actually easier than I thought.